# ParameterizedThreadStart error, no overload for 'subroutine' matches delegate ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to create a thread which creates generates new RSA keys using my algorithm provided.
The algorithm may not be perfect but is fine by what i am doing - not the problem.
The problem lies with why doesnt the parts below work: from what i have gathered online i am using parameterizedthreadstart correctly?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GenerateKeys)); //issue here!!!!
        thread.Start(RSA_KEYS, PublicKeysToDistribute);
```

it shows the error: no overload for 'GenerateKeys' matches delegate ParameterizedThreadStart.
Any help would be appreciated

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Dictionary<(BigInteger, BigInteger), (BigInteger, BigInteger)> RSA_KEYS = new Dictionary<(BigInteger, BigInteger), (BigInteger, BigInteger)>();
        Queue<(BigInteger, BigInteger)> PublicKeysToDistribute = new Queue<(BigInteger, BigInteger)>();


        Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GenerateKeys));
        thread.Start(RSA_KEYS, PublicKeysToDistribute);

    //recipitent receives public key in form e,n
    //splits into Biginteger array : {e,n}
    GenerateKeys(RSA_KEYS, PublicKeysToDistribute);


        BigInteger[] PublicKey = Array.ConvertAll(PublicKeyRequest(PublicKeysToDistribute).Split(':'), BigInteger.Parse);

        string input;
        //creates message to encrypt            
        input = InputToAscii();
        //encrypt using PublicKey
        BigInteger a = encrypt(PublicKey, input);
        BigInteger b = decrypt((RSA_KEYS[(PublicKey[0], PublicKey[1])]).Item1, (RSA_KEYS[(PublicKey[0], PublicKey[1])]).Item2, a);
        Console.WriteLine(AsciiToOutput(b));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string PublicKeyRequest(Queue<(BigInteger, BigInteger)> PublicKeysToDistribute)
    {
        string publickey = PublicKeysToDistribute.Peek().Item1 + ":" +PublicKeysToDistribute.Peek().Item2;
        PublicKeysToDistribute.Dequeue();
        return publickey;
    }

    //create a key value pair where the publickey is key and private key is value
    //publickey = {biginteger,biginteger} where {e,n}
    //privatekey = {biginteger,biginteger} where {d,n}
    public static void GenerateKeys(Dictionary<(BigInteger, BigInteger), (BigInteger, BigInteger)> RSA_KEYS, Queue<(BigInteger, BigInteger)> PublicKeysToDistribute)
    {
        int p = 4201; //default use 61  4201
        int q = 4007; //default use 53  4007
        int n = p * q;


        // compute the totient, phi
        int ϕn = (p - 1) * (q - 1);


        //e for random number which 1 < e < ϕn and is co prime of ϕn
        Random rn = new Random();
        bool found = false;
        BigInteger e = 0;

        while (found == false)
        {
            e = rn.Next(1, ϕn);
            if (Coprime(ϕn, e) == true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        // where (d * e) mod ϕn = 1 find d

        BigInteger d = 0;


        for (int k = 1; k < ϕn; k++)
        {
            if ((k * e) % ϕn == 1)
            {
                d = k;
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("p="+p+",q="+q+",n="+n+",phi="+ϕn+",e="+e+",d="+d+",n="+n);
        Console.WriteLine("Public key: e = " + e + " n = " + n);
        Console.WriteLine("Private key: d = " + d + " n = " + n);
        RSA_KEYS.Add((e, n), (d, n));
        PublicKeysToDistribute.Enqueue((e, n));
        Console.WriteLine("added new key to dictionary");

        //return new KeyValuePair<(BigInteger, BigInteger), (BigInteger, BigInteger)>((e,n),(d,n));
    }

    private static BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger[] PublicKey, string input)
    {
        BigInteger m = BigInteger.Parse(input); //m = message
        BigInteger c = eMod(m, PublicKey[0], PublicKey[1]); //cipher text = (message ^ e) mod n
        return c;
    }

    private static BigInteger decrypt(BigInteger d, BigInteger n, BigInteger c)
    {
        BigInteger f = eMod(c, d, n); //result test = cipher ^ d mod n

        return f;
    }

    private static BigInteger eMod(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger c) //where a^b % c;
    {
        //base case
        if (b == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (b % 2 == 0)
        {
            BigInteger d = eMod(a, b / 2, c);
            //int result = d * d % c;
            return ((d * d) % c);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((a % c) * eMod(a, b - 1, c)) % c;
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger GetGCDByModulus(BigInteger value1, BigInteger value2)
    {
        while (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0)
        {
            if (value1 > value2)
                value1 %= value2;
            else
                value2 %= value1;
        }
        return BigInteger.Max(value1, value2);
    }

    private static bool Coprime(BigInteger value1, BigInteger value2)
    {
        return GetGCDByModulus(value1, value2) == 1;
    }

    private static string InputToAscii()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter values to encrypt:");
        char[] input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray(); //-1 < input < 999;

        //char[] input = "-1".ToCharArray();
        string AsciiInput = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            AsciiInput += ((int)input[i]).ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(AsciiInput);
        return AsciiInput;
    }

    private static string AsciiToOutput(BigInteger input)
    {
        string inputstring = input.ToString();
        string output = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            output += (char)Convert.ToInt32((inputstring.Substring(i * 2, 2)));
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The single parameter for a `ParameterizedThreadStart` is of type `object`, which you would cast to the actual type to access your data.  You have specified two parameters of more-derived types.

Comment: you are doing it wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=net-6.0

Comment: Don’t use threads, use tasks, e.g. `Task.Run(() => GenerateKeys(RSAKEYS, PublicKeysToDistribute));`